# Dynamically adding to JScrollPane without removing child components

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently adding JPanels to a JScrollPane by pressing a button:

[image: JScrollPane before adding child panel]

[image: JScrollPane after adding child panel]

However, I can't get the panels to stack on top of each other when adding more than 1 panel to the scroll pane. The previously added panel in the scroll pane seems to be getting removed when I call getViewport().add().

Is there a way to get a JScrollPane to save it's children and make my GUI look like this when adding multiple JPanels with a button press?

[image: Mockup of what it should look like]

1. MainWindow class:

   ```
   JScrollPane trackerPanel = new JScrollPane();
   trackerPanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
   trackerPanel.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
   trackerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
   frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, trackerPanel);
   frame.setVisible(true);

   //method: called from EnterButtonListener to create and append TrackerTile to GUI
   public void addTrackerTile() {
       incrementTrackerPanelCounter();
       TrackerTile trackerTile = new TrackerTile();
       trackerPanel.getViewport().add(trackerTile);
   }
   ```
2. TrackerTile class:

   ```
   public class TrackerTile extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

   public Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(794, 100);

   public TrackerTile() {
       setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
   }    

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       return preferredSize;
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
       return new Dimension(794, 100);
   } 

   public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
       return 128;
   }

   public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
       return 128;
   }

   public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
       return false;
   }

   public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
       return false;
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic logic to create the GUI should be:

```
JPanel somePanel = new JPanel( some layout );
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( somePanel );
frame.add(scrollPane. BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then in the `ActionListener` that adds new panels you just do:

```
somePanel.add( new TrackerTile() );
```

So its just like adding components to a panel. The only difference is that the panal has been added to a scroll pane.

There is no need to implement `Scrollable`. But if you really want to customize the `Scrollable properties`, then you need to implement Scrollable on the "somePanel", not the individual components you add to "somePanel".

Or another option is to use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/) which implements the `Scrollable` interface and has methods that allow you to customize the behaviour.

Comment: JPanels are being added at runtime, so the JScrollPane viewport is being changed but it's not retaining previously JPanels that were added to the viewport.

Comment: @Simmeringc, because your logic is wrong. I just told you the proper way to solve the problem. You don't keep adding panels to the viewport. Only one component can ever exist in the viewport at one time. You need to add components to the base panel that you added to the viewport.

Comment: So is there a way to create that tile like structure from my pictures? I think I see what you're saying adding panels to a panel in a scroll pane.

Comment: @Simmeringc How would you do it if you were not using a scroll pane? You create a "main" panel, then you add "child" panels to the "main" panel. That part of the logic doesn't change. The only difference is you don't add the "main" panel to the frame. You add the "main" panel to a scroll panel and add the scroll pane to the frame.

Comment: So when add a bunch of child panels to my parent panel, what's the proper way to change the dimensions of the parent panel and get it to scroll.

Comment: @Simmeringc, Never specify the dimensions of the panel, that is the job of the layout manager. The only thing you need to do is add components to the "main" panel, then you need to invoke `revalidate()` on the "main" panel, to invoke the layout manager (sometimes you may also need to invoke "repaint()").  The layout manager will determine the preferred size of the "main" panel dynamically as you add components to the panel. The scrollbars will appear automatically when needed.